# Paypal not calling IPN script at all on my web server

Tags: paypal-ipn

I'm trying to use Paypal IPN on a website.

- The payment works and is marked as "completed".
- The return url works.
- An email is sent notifying the payment is done

But it seems paypal doesn't talk to the IPN script. When checking with Wireshark, there is no communication with my website when the payment is sent.

1. Could it be because this communication is embedded inside an SSL communication and not in non-secure HTTP?
2. Could my server refuse to process the IPN request from Paypal?

I thought it would work out of the box, but no. It seems it doesn't reach my server, and Paypal doesn't return something like "your server refused to receive IPN infos". So Paypal is just not calling IPN script.

I'm 99% sure my request in correct, but here's the button I made:

```
<form action="<%=paypalurl%>" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<%=appsettings.paypalemail%>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<%=appsettings.paypalitem%>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<%=appsettings.paypalid%>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%=appsettings.paypalamount%>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<%=appsettings.paypalcurrency%>">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<%=userid%>">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.mysite.com/ipnscript.aspx">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mysite.com/ppreturnurl.aspx">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.mysite.com/ppcancelurl.aspx">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif"  border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you make sure that IPN is enabled?

Account -> My Profile -> Instant Payment Notification Preferences

Secondly I would check the IPN History

Account -> History -> IPN History

This will allow you to see the status and re-send it if need be.

- I am assuming you are using the sandbox to test this out first.

Comment: Another simple check to make in general is to ensure that your IPN notify URL is correct especially if it is dynamically generated. Always use logging to track exactly what logic is being hit in your code for IPN transactions and as PayPal recommends always log your transactions.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2013-06-20, if you have a Business account, to enable IPN messages:

(Log into PayPal) > Profile > My Selling Tools > Getting paid and managing my risk / Instant payment notifications / Update > Choose IPN Settings > (o) Receive IPN messages (Enabled) > Save

*Note: you can leave "Notification URL" blank if you provide a "notify_url" field in your payment form / button code.

Comment: For the sandbox, I cannot leave the "Notification URL" blank. I get an error: "you must enter a properly formatted URL..."...Then if I enter a Notification URL in the profile as well as in my API, the IPN with the transaction id goes to the URL specified in my profile...which is not the one I want it to go to.